# Model Serializer destroy method

Tags: django, serialization, http-delete

I have a model named `Profile` which is a wrapper over the `User` model of Django. Now, I have created a `ProfileSerializer` in the following way:

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        user = User.objects.create_user(**user_data, username=validated_data.get('username'))
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user, **validated_data)
        return profile
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.dob = validated_data.get('dob', instance.dob)
        instance.karma = validated_data.get('karma', instance.karma)
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        instance.user.first_name = user_data.get('first_name', instance.user.first_name)
        instance.user.last_name = user_data.get('last_name', instance.user.last_name)
        instance.user.email = user_data.get('email', instance.user.email)
        instance.user.username = instance.username
        new_password = user_data.get('password')
        if new_password:
            instance.user.set_password(new_password)
        instance.user.save()
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

The problem here is, when I am trying to **DELETE** a profile, the profile is getting deleted but the user still stays. I need to be able to delete a user as well when a **DELETE** request is made.

I tried to do some search but I couldn't find and `destroy` or `delete` methods for a `ModelSerializer`.

Comment: Mention Django version and include models

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this on view level with `perform_destroy` method:

```
class DetailProfile(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    lookup_field = 'username'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'username'

    def perform_destroy(self, instance):
        user = instance.user
        instance.delete()
        user.delete()
```

Comment: That is inconsistent on Drf's part. How can update/create be performed in the serializer while the destroy operation is not?